# build a JSON from Django-mptt

Tags: json, django

I am trying to build up a json from a tree structure. I use django-mptt to build the tree. But impossible for me to create a JSON out of it.

I want the json to look like this:

```
[
        {"name": "Parent 1",
            "child": [
                {"name": "Child 1-1"},
                {"name": "Child 1-2"},
                {"name": "Child 1-3"}
            ]},
        {"name": "Parent 2",
            "child": [
                {"name": "Child 2-1"},
                {"name": "Child 2-2"},
                {"name": "Child 2-3"
                    ,"child": [
                    {"name": "Child 2-3-1"},
                    {"name": "Child 2-3-2"}                 
                    ]
                }
             ]
        }       
    ];
```

It can have multiple/unlimited children.

So far I tried this. But unable to get the right syntax for the JSON

```
var json = [
            {% recursetree nodes %}

                {"text": "{{ node.item_title }}"
                    {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                        ,"nodes": [
                            {{ children }}
                    {% endif %}
                        },
            {% endrecursetree %}

        ];
```

This gets me this output:

```
var json = [
    {"name": "Parent 1"
        ,"child": [
            {"name": "Child 1-1"        
            },
            {"name": "Child 1-2"        
            },
            {"name": "Child 1-3"        
            },
            },
    {"name": "Parent 2"     
        ,"child": [
            {"name": "Child 2-1"        
            },
            {"name": "Child 2-2"        
            },
            {"name": "Child 2-3"        
                ,"child": [
                    {"name": "Child 2-3-1"      
                    },
                    {"name": "Child 2-3-2"      
                    },
                    },
        ];
```

I cant figure out how to get the parentesis and hooks at the right places.

I'm really stuck! Can somebody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Don't try and build up JSON in a template; do it in the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Now I'm totally lost. Django-mptt documentation does not cover this at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you give me an example how this is done?